# Symfony2 MissingMandatoryParametersException when parameter is present

Tags: symfony

Color me confused. I'm getting this error intermittently.

```
[2015-02-16 10:29:51] request.INFO: Matched route "app_site_default_edittargetsubmit" (parameters: "_controller": "App\SiteBundle\Controller\DefaultController::editTargetSubmitAction", "id": "17", "_route": "app_site_default_edittargetsubmit") [] []
[2015-02-16 10:29:51] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2015-02-16 10:29:51] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2015-02-16 10:29:51] security.DEBUG: Username "user@example.com" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2015-02-16 10:29:51] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: "Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "adminCustomerTargets"." at /var/www/mysite/site/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1264 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing (\"id\") to generate a URL for route \"adminCustomerTargets\". at /var/www/ourbrightlink/site/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1264)"} []
[2015-02-16 10:29:51] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

As you can see in the list of parameters in the first line of the exception, the id parameter *is* there.
(parameters: "_controller": "App\SiteBundle\Controller\DefaultController::editTargetSubmitAction", **"id": "17"**, "_route": "app_site_default_edittargetsubmit").

The route is defined via annotation:

```
  /**
   * Handles the submission of the Edit form.
   *
   * @route( "target/edit/{id}" )
   * @method( {"POST"} )
   * @template( "AppSiteBundle:Default:editTarget.html.twig" )
   * @param Request $request
   * @param  $id
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   */
  public function editTargetSubmitAction( Request $request, $id )
  { ... }
```

This is Symfony 2.5.6.

Suggestions?
TIA

Comment: I noticed the `@Route` annotation is missing the route name, which in this case is `app_site_default_edittargetsubmit`. Have you defined this route name elsewhere?

Comment: I am using the default route name for this route. No. It isn't defined anywhere else. - Thanks

Comment: This is happening with other routes as well. In all cases, intermittently.

Comment: I may have found the answer to this at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150543/whats-wrong-with-this-symfony2-route?rq=1[/link]. I'll post when I know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post noted above is, indeed, the answer.
This error occurs not when matching a URL to a route, but when *generating a URL from a route*. This happens when the second parameter is absent in the call to generateUrl().